# Why does the 'disks' app and 'system monitor' show different capacity for the swap on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, swap, gnome-system-monitor

Context:

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on a lenovo legion y540 laptop with dual hard disks. ubuntu 18.04 on 128GB m.2 and windows 10 on the second drive-ssd. When I installed ubuntu I chose 15GB swap space. The machine has 16GB ram.

Problem:
When I open system monitor application, it shows the system as 2gb of swap but on the 'disks' app, it shows the swap as 15gb as I allocated. Why is this discrepeancy?

[image: system monitor and disks output]

Answer (score 0):

Your 15GB partition isn’t active (“Swap (version 1) — Not Active”), so that’s not where your system is storing the 2GB of swap it’s configured with. I’m guessing your active swap volume is on your other drive, or in a file.

To see what swap is in use, run

```
/sbin/swapon
```

in a terminal.

To enable your 15GB swap partition, add

```
UUID=33e3aead-68d1-4e67-98f7-2fcb2150bcf9 swap swap default 0 0
```

to `/etc/fstab`, and run

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The result says `/swapfile file 2G 0B -2`. How do I 'activate' the swap that I created?

Comment: See my updated answer.